# Add class to selected option of a select element

Tags: asp.net, jquery

To demonstrate that I could even use a Class attribute on an option elem I tried adding class attributes to options of a select elem in a static page and that works fine. I noticed that not many online resouces documented this so I figured I would explicitly set the record.

here is the jquery code attempting to add a class to the selected option

```
 ChangeDdlItemBG : function(obj, compLev)
{
    var ddl = $(obj);
    var index = ddl.attr('selectedIndex');
    switch(compLev)
    {
        case ComplianceLevel.Compliant : 
            $(ddl.attr('id') + ': selected').addClass('Compliant');
            break;
        case ComplianceLevel.OtherThanSerious : 
            $(ddl.attr('id') + ': selected').addClass('OtherThanSerious');
            break;
        case ComplianceLevel.Serious : 
            $(ddl.attr('id') + ': selected').addClass('Serious');
            break;
        case ComplianceLevel.Critical : 
            $(ddl.attr('id') + ': selected').addClass('Critical');
            break;
    }
}

var ComplianceLevel =
{
    Compliant : function() { return 0; },
    OtherThanSerious : function() { return 1; },
    Serious : function() { return 2; },
    Critical : function() { return 3; },
};
```

New information, I found the reason nothing occured was a simple mistake in the value being passed in for compLev. However, now it runs through the code for the correct case and does nothing to the color of the item.

Comment: I apologize, this is a question ... the code posted above does not behave how I would expect. The classes have a background-color rule declared to change the background color of the selected item.  Do i need a postback to occur for this to show?

Comment: @Matthew You need to run that function on the change event of the SELECT element. In that case, you don't need to pass in the reference to the element since the `this` value refers to it.

Comment: @Sime Vidas, I most certainly am running the function in an onchance event inside the select elm.

Comment: @Matthew Are you doing it like so: `<select onchange=" /* code */ ">`?

Comment: correct, however it calls a separate method first which then makes a call to ChangeDdlItemBG.

Comment: @Matthew Avoid that. Digg into separation of content and behavior, and also unobtrusive JavaScript. Event handlers should be defined in JavaScript: `$("select").change(function() { /* code */ });`

Comment: I do not want to attempt using a event handling because that requires specifying the name of the elm. As I said, I am using a repeater and that gives them interesting names that i will not know at compile time. especially as i get down in tier levels (i.e repeaters within repeaters).

Comment: @Matthew The selector does not have to be an ID. You can select based on a class or based on inheritance. For example `$("#container select")` will select all SELECT elements inside the element with the "container" ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly reduce the redundancy.

Also, you have to **run** the functions, in order to compare their return value with compLev:

```
function(obj, compLev) {

    var optClass = "";

    switch (compLev) {
    case ComplianceLevel.Compliant() : 
        optClass = 'Compliant';
        break;
    case ComplianceLevel.OtherThanSerious() : 
        optClass = 'OtherThanSerious';
        break;
    case ComplianceLevel.Serious() : 
        optClass = 'Serious';
        break;
    case ComplianceLevel.Critical() : 
        optClass = 'Critical';
        break;
    }

    $(obj).find("option:selected").addClass(optClass).siblings().removeClass();

}
```

Comment: so the idea would be to bind an event to the select elm then perform the changes within the callback func?

Comment: also bear in mind, I am running the functions in markup in an onchange event for the select elm. I just didn't think it was necessary code to post.

Comment: @Matthew Do you want that only the selected option has the class set? Or every option?

Comment: Another note, there are multiple drop down lists upwards of 50. The number is not known at compile time because I am using a repeater (ASP.NET control) to create them.

Comment: @Matthew Where does the compLev value come from?

Comment: omg you are a genius. Can you explain to me what is happening with the 
siblings().removeClass(); part

Comment: just grabs all elms within parent elm and strips any class attributes?

Comment: @Matthew You want that only the currently selected OPTION element has a class set. That's why I 1. search for the currently selected OPTION element, 2. set its class, 3. select all its sibling OPTION elements, 4. remove all classes from them.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your selectors have a typo. Unless `ddl.attr('id')` is a type of element, your code doesn't add classes to anything. I think you want `$('#' + ddl.attr('id') + ':selected')`

Comment: I tried your style originally. It produces a syntax exception.